# How to assign one X Screen to one LightDM seat?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, lightdm, multiseat

I'm trying to configure a multiseat setup on a desktop PC with

- two keyboards
- two mice
- two monitors attached to **the same** graphics card (Nvidia NVS 310)

Using these [instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiseatTeam/Instructions) I managed to make LightDM start two seats and `udev` will exclusively assign the same mouse and keyboard to the same seat every time.

**Problem**: `udev` could assign a graphics card exclusively to one seat, but there's only one card. `udev` (I think) cannot assign one monitor to one seat.

**Wish**: I'd like to solve this without buying a second graphics card, as this affects a lot of PCs in my pool.

**Idea**: `xorg.conf` allows to configure separate X Screens for every monitor (see e.g. NVIDIA's [manual](http://de.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/FreeBSD-x86_64/304.60/README/configmultxscreens.html)). As far as I understand, every X Screen get's it's own X Server.

Now is it possible to assign an X Screen exclusively to one LightDM seat?

Comment: This is my exact problem. Did you find a solution thus far? It looks like the only solution is to create two X screens but I really don't see how to assign each screen to a specific seat...

Comment: @AlexisWilke I bought a second Nvidia card ...